# Magento Cart, Strange behavior

Tags: magento, cart

Hi I am getting strange behavior in Magento cart. Some random products been adding to all the customers. I think these products are from last cart sessions. Please help!

Comment: is it really that strange ? check here http://www.cdotsys.com/persistent-shopping-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Create database backup then truncate this tables:

- sales_flat_quote
- sales_flat_quote_address
- sales_flat_quote_address_item
- sales_flat_quote_item
- sales_flat_quote_item_option
- sales_flat_quote_payment
- sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate

NOTE: Possible to lose some statistics (best selling products, popular products etc.).

Comment: I think magento doesn't have any solution for this. I did truncate the table. I changed cookie domain to same domain i am using ( I removed and kept it blank), i did almost all the suggestions provided in forums. I don't think magento can be a solution. Trying to switch it to some other platforms. Magento is like a big elephant putting mud on its own feet.

Comment: In my case it happens only once, when someone came to site for a first time, or every time when I delete cookies in browser.

Comment: I found this is something related to trailing slash. When i hit /checkout/cart/ its showing correct session but when i hit /checkout/cart its showing some random products. Also if i add ?___SID=U at the end session works correctly. Any idea?

Comment: I turned off "Use SID on Frontend" in configuration, but it didn't help.. only when I truncated mentioned tables it started to work as it should be..